# How can I create errors in kubernetes pod from max memory or cpu usage

Tags: kubernetes, max

I am trying to create errors on a Kubernetes pod so that I can test our pod healthcheck monitoring is working. I have looked into running a command on the command line to suck up CPU and memory usage but have not been able to stress the pod.

I do not have root access on the pod so cannot install tools (eg stress or python) to max out the pod memory or CPU usage.

Comment: What is your pod running?

Comment: Can you edit the pod spec to add a sidecar with `stress`?

Comment: Pod is running Debian Linux 4.14.67-coreos